# QMediaPlayer - length of video

Tags: qt, video

I have coded two versions of video player based on QMediaPlayer and on Vlc-qt. In both cases I have the incorrect value for the full time video. The player show me that total time is 7 seconds, but in fact the time approx. 5 minutes. And of course, the slider of position shows not correct.

I was confused, so that maybe I did something wrong. But this video file was tested with MS video player, and I see the same problem.

Video for testing can be found at https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgCzZ90Ttbz65jqiluS2NS95Id0U

My guess is that the file contains the wrong information about the time. Or maybe not codec provides such information in not correct way.

Can anybody clarify to me what the reason of the problem and how it should be fixed.

Comment: `the file contains the wrong information about the time` -> you're right, and there's nothing you can do about it (maybe re-encoding it)

Comment: ok thank you very much!